# testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid

Tags: maven, webdriver, testng

When I run the selenium test cases using maven and it displays warning message: [WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

anyone knows?

Comment: Why not using a more up2date testng version?

Comment: thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of TestNG and your problem will be resolved.

If you are using maven, try putting following dependency in pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the surefire plugin version in pom.xml might resolve you problem.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my errors:
Select Project --> right click and go to Properties --> select TestNG--> select Maven - select checkbox for 'Enable project specific settings'.